# Apache Solr Date Searching

Tags: solr, dtsearch

I am working on two different searching tools: DtSearch and Solr. I do a FULL_TEXT search on  one indexed search term ("2008/12/02") and unfortunately both give different hits though the data are the same. Another strange thing I notice is that Solr gives three DOC_ID as hits and DtSearch gives me five for the same search terms.

I am confused about date searching now. How can it be possible though the data are the same? 
Do I need to apply some extra settings in config files? Is there any way I get consistent output?

Thank you,

Comment: which one is correct ?? whats the solr configuration for date field ?

Comment: The correct Output given by DtSearch.

Comment: can you provide the input data ? field type in solr ? and how you are querying the data ?

Comment: Input date seems to large but I am searching on full text data. and Text data contains text like 
02/12/2003, 
Tuesday February 12, 2003,
02-12-2003,
2-12-2003

My browser URL generate this query syntax:
//localhost:9080/Solr/0000101011/select?q=02%2F12%2F2003&st=off&docHitDetailRequired=off&hitOffsetRequired=off&fl=FULL_TEXT&wt=xml

Regarding the field type I check it is define properly.